# How to change year and month in a date which is in datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe (8000 rows) with a datetime format column, which has dates like YYYY-MM-DD. I am looking to change it from being a single date to multiple months, and years, with same day.

My Output:

```
0  data-1  2011-12-03
1  data-2  2011-12-03
2  data-3  2011-12-03
..
..
   data-4  2011-12-03
   data-5  2011-12-03
7999  data-6  2011-12-03
```

Expected output:

```
     val1        date
0  data-1  2009-01-03
..         2009-02-03
           2009-03-03
           ..
           ..
           2009-11-03
           2009-12-03
11  data-n 2010-01-03
..         2010-02-03
           2010-03-03
           ..
           ..
           2010-11-03
           2010-12-03
           2011-01-03
..         2011-02-03
           2011-03-03
           ..
           ..
           2011-11-03
7999  data-m  2011-12-03
```

I want it to spread over the 12 months and 5 years.
I tried:

```
df.date[0:999] = pd.to_datetime(stallion_df.date[0:999]) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
df.date[0:999] = pd.to_datetime(stallion_df.date[0:999]) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
...
```

for 8000 rows for year and month, which is clearly not optimal.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @enke Thanks for the response. I have made the changes.

Comment: All dates are `2011-12-03`, I want it to be a range of dates instead of a single date. I am trying to change it intentionally for other purposes.

Comment: I am more concerned about `date` column than `val1` column. So you can consider `val1` column currently being irrelevant. I just need a range a range of years and months with same date.

Comment: `2018-01-01` to `2022-12-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your expected output? It's constructing the Cartesian product of dates ranging from `'2018-01-03'` to `'2022-12-03'` and `val` column. You have `date-1` to `date-m`, so I substituted `m` with 100. Then you'll get 6000 rows.

```
m = 100
out = (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'date-{i}' for i in range(1,m+1)], 
                            pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2022-12-01', freq='MS') + pd.DateOffset(days=2)])
       .to_frame(name=['val','date']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
           val       date
0       date-1 2018-01-03
1       date-1 2018-02-03
2       date-1 2018-03-03
3       date-1 2018-04-03
4       date-1 2018-05-03
...        ...        ...
5995  date-100 2022-08-03
5996  date-100 2022-09-03
5997  date-100 2022-10-03
5998  date-100 2022-11-03
5999  date-100 2022-12-03

[6000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may basically use *date_range* to create a series to be added:

```
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='1/3/2009', end='3/11/2011', freq='M'))
```

Just replace it with your desired start and end date. It will automatically increase months and years by keeping the last day of each month. If you want to set the day to a specific one:

```
dates.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=3))
```

This returns the same but with day 3 for all entries. If you also want a larger series with repeated days, you may use *repeat* as:

```
dates.repeat(10).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So this way you will have the same series but each date is repeated 10 times.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, but I need a list ranging upto 8000 plus rows. Every date would be repeated about 9 to 10 times. This only gives a list of dates. I am trying to work upon this though.

Comment: Why not use `dates.repeat(10)` for example? This will extend your series by repeating each date 10 times. I have edited my answer above with the continuation of the example.